# getting ids from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

a team table which containd a team ID and a team name and then 2 further tables that contain data from a quiz and another with data from a questionnaire.

I need to get a list of team IDs that have completed BOTH the quiz (so have some quiz data) AND the questionnaire (so have some questionnaire data) but I can't see how to join the 3 tables to get the list of ids I need.

Any pointers greatly received

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) ??

Comment: Please tell us your all three table structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in upper comment..

> I actually want team IDs that are in either of the data tables. How
>   would that amend the query? – Dave

Try this, This is what I understood with your words..

```
select teamID,teamName from team where teamID in (select teamID from quiz) or teamID in (select teamID from questionnaire);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I ended up using this method as it gave me the correct result if either table was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some reference of team table inside quiz and questionaire tables, you will need to make a join this way -

```
SELECT team.id, team.name
from 
 team, quiz, questionnaire
where
 team.id=quiz.team_id
 AND team.id=questionnaire.team_id
```

when you do `team.id=quiz.team_id AND team.id=questionnaire.team_id` only those team IDs which are present in both quiz and questionnaire tables willbe shown in the result.

---

If you need team ID which exists in either of the tables quiz or questionaire, then you will to replace `AND` by `OR`-

```
SELECT team.id, team.name
from 
 team, quiz, questionnaire
where
 team.id=quiz.team_id
 OR team.id=questionnaire.team_id
```

Comment: How do you know the other 2 tables contain the team id ?

Comment: This is assuming that quiz and questionaire tables have the reference. The second sentence of OP says that quiz and questionaire table both have team related data. I might be wrong with my assumption, it is possible that the structure is using some cross-reference table for that. This is just a possible answer assuming there is some reference already in quiz and questionaire. Edited my answer

Comment: Hi, you are quite right to assume that the team ID is in both the data tables, but I was a little incorrect in my original post. I actually want team IDs that are in either of the data tables. How would that amend the query?

Comment: In that case you will need to use 'OR' instead of 'AND'. See, my updated answer above.